# Preserve tablesorter order on postback

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tablesorter, rowdatabound

I'm using a Tablesorter 2.0 plugin with Gridview on ASP.NET. I used this code to fix the `THEAD` problem :

```
if (GridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
   {
      GridView1.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
      GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
      GridView1.FooterRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;
   }
```

Everything worked fine with sorting rows, but the problem begins when I used this code to do `postback` when clicking on each row

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            e.Row.Attributes("onclick") = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)
        End If
End Sub
```

Tablesorter keeps working well, I can sort columns, however when I click on a row on my gridview to do a postback as 
`<tr onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$GridView1','Select$1')">` my previous sorted rows return to their original positions as if loaded the first time, and don't preserve the sort I did. Just in case, I'm also using a `UpdatePanel`

Answer (score 0):

I have a [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) which has a [saveSort widget](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-savesort.html) which saves the current sort to local storage, with a cookie fallback. Sadly the widget won't work on the original version of tablesorter.